# Hide pictures from article preview

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm learning Django by making a news / blog web app. On my home page i would like to list my articles so i made a simple template with this :

```html
    {% for article in last_articles %}
        <div class="article">
            <h3>{{ article.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ article.content | truncatewords_html:80 | safe }}</p>
            <p><a href="{% url 'read' slug=article.slug id=article.id %}">Read More</a> </p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
    {% empty %}
        <p>Nothing for the moment</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that I have some pictures on my article.content so my question is : Is there a way to remove them like truncatewords but for picture. I didn't find solutions on official doc.

Thanks

Comment: `.article img {display: none}` ?

Comment: @IvanStarostin ok thank you, I was focused on learning the django and I did not do CSS at all for the moment ...
I should have thought about it ...
thank you